# How can I change view of inflater?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I want to change Inflated view of main_inflater by click each button.

here is my source code;

I initiated My two buttons and setOnListener to two buttons.

But inflater just show the views that is inflated first time.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//optionmenu
int titleHeight;
int mainHeight;
int menuHeight;

//objects
TextView tv_status;
Tabbar tb_status;
LinearLayout titleLayout;
LinearLayout mainLayout;
LinearLayout menuLayout;
Button btn1;
Button btn2;

LayoutInflater main_inflater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout_init();
    btn_init();


}   

public void layout_init() {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    titleHeight = 2*deviceHeight/26;
    mainHeight = 21*deviceHeight/26;
    menuHeight = 3*deviceHeight/26;

    main_inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //initiate Layouts
    titleLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.title_layout);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    menuLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu_layout);

    titleLayout.getLayoutParams().height = titleHeight;
    mainLayout.getLayoutParams().height = mainHeight;
    menuLayout.getLayoutParams().height = menuHeight;

    main_inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, mainLayout, true);


}

public void btn_init() {
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
    {
        main_inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, mainLayout, false);
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button2)
    {
        main_inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_info, mainLayout, false);}

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() , "id : "+v.getId() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


}
```

}

toast message is working. But inflater didn't change view.
plz tell me why bbbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onClick method, you are passing false as last parameter to inflate. This prevents the inflated layout from being attached to the root.
Try passing true as last parameter, as shown below:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
    {
        mainLayout.removeAllViews();
        main_inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, mainLayout, true);
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button2)
    {
        mainLayout.removeAllViews();
        main_inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_info, mainLayout, true);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext() , "id : "+v.getId() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();    
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing all views from mainLayout, before inflating into it? I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Inflater does nothing but inflate the view, that is, to convert the xml of `viewpager_layout.xml` to an actual object, which is a `View` or a subclass of `View`.

If you are trying to set the view of the entire Activity...

Replace

```
main_inflater.inflater(R.layout.viewpager_layout, mainLayout, true);
```

with the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 3 layouts? An activity can only have 1 layout at a time, and in that layout there will be subviews.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. Maybe It would be solution to change from  inflater to setContentView as you said. Thank you. but Each layout contains same titlelayout and same menulayout... it sounds likes inefficient for me